# ImportXLM Function Using Regex

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am somewhat new to google sheets and would appreciate any help/guidance - thank you!
I am attempting to extract the number of likes into a cell (line is highlighted in picture). I have not be able to successfully use REGEX and ImportXLM.

Here's what I have:

```
=IMPORTXML(B2,"//meta[@property='og:description']/@content")
```

The cell prints "Unwind to these calm classical guitar pieces." - I'm honestly not sure where it got this from.

[image: Code]

Thank you again!

Edit: Here is the URL: https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DXaImRpG7HXqp?si=CLmKZPExTAyzo0ZuZWKgfA

I can extract pretty much everything but the og:description. It just prints the description

Comment: Can you say what is the html URL you are using? I.e. What is in cell B2?

Comment: whats the url ?

Comment: Thanks for your replies! Here is the URL: https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DXaImRpG7HXqp?si=WYDB_vb0TzGTNZZVClKSKA

Comment: B2 is the URL. For some reason it does not print anything with og: in fornt of it. I cant basically get everything else/

Comment: It just prints the description, not the og:description

Comment: @player0 Spot on! Thank you so much! Highly appreciated

Comment: @player0 If it's not a spotify playlist made my spotify it says the content is empty. Do you know how I would change this? Here is an example link of it saying empty. https://open.spotify.com/playlist/20u0777HMcRxVXB8LKaVnn?si=MiaKKAPRSHaZNuYI7Ta5cg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(A1), 500, 5), 
 "select Col5 where Col4 contains 'followers'", 0), "\d+")*1)
```

[image]

---

### fix:

```
=INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(A2), 500, 5), 
 "select Col5 where Col4 contains 'followers'", 0), 
 QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(A2), 500, 7), 
 "select Col7 where Col6 contains 'followers'", 0)), "\d+")*1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is great thanks! For some reason it doesn't work for some playlists. Any ideas on changes I would need to make? Example URL: https://open.spotify.com/playlist/4lkiAA9uhdQK2WeGrxMVOB?si=EdJZsxB5R6ypVbuUmSCyyw

Comment: You're the best - works perfectly. Thank you so much!!